# .NET nanoframework: Assembly references cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, microcontroller, esp32, nanoframework

I am trying to use the Iot.Device.Bmxx80 library for a very simple project with my ESP32-WROOM development board. However, I am unable to deploy and run it on my system, because the system seems not to be able to load the necessary assemblies on the device.

To reproduce it, just create a new blank .NET nanoframework project and add the following NuGet packages (the default program is sufficent - no need to change it):

- nanoFramework.Hardware.Esp32
- nanoFramework.Iot.Device.Bmxx80

After that, just run the application on the microcontroller.

In the output tab, I get the following error output, after all libraries are deployed to it:

```
    Resolving.
Link failure: some assembly references cannot be resolved!!

Assembly: Iot.Device.Bmxx80 (1.0.0.0) needs assembly 'UnitsNet.Pressure' (1.0.0.0)
Assembly: Iot.Device.Bmxx80 (1.0.0.0) needs assembly 'UnitsNet.Temperature' (1.0.0.0)
Assembly: Iot.Device.Bmxx80 (1.0.0.0) needs assembly 'UnitsNet.RelativeHumidity' (1.0.0.0)
Assembly: Iot.Device.Bmxx80 (1.0.0.0) needs assembly 'UnitsNet.Length' (1.0.0.0)
Assembly: Iot.Device.Bmxx80 (1.0.0.0) needs assembly 'UnitsNet.Duration' (1.0.0.0)
Assembly: Iot.Device.Bmxx80 (1.0.0.0) needs assembly 'UnitsNet.ElectricResistance' (1.0.0.0)
Error: a3000000
Waiting for debug commands...
The program '[1] .NET nanoFramework application: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Confirmed issue with NuGets. Issue opened. Please track [here] (https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues/815).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by Jose, it was a bug that was fixed in the mentioned GitHub issue. The code is working fine now.